# How can I update the User object in Parse (JavaScript SDK)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

I have the following view which submits a form containing data to be updated to the current user:

```
EditMyProfileView = Parse.View.extend({
        template: Handlebars.compile($('#edit-my-profile-tpl').html()),
        events: {
            'submit .profile-details-edit': 'submit'
        },
        submit: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var form = document.getElementById("profile-details-edit");

            var FullName = form.FullName.value;
            var bio = form.bio.value;

            user = Parse.User.current();
            user.set("FullName", FullName);
            user.set("bio", bio);
            form.submit();
            user.save();

        },
        render: function(){
            var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
            this.$el.html(this.template(attributes));
        }
    }),
```

This is the form that submits the data:

```
           <form class="profile-details-edit" id="profile-details-edit" role="form">
                <p><label for="FullName"><b>Full Name</b></label><br><input type="text" id="FullName" name="FullName" maxLength="20" class="form-control" placeholder="{{FullName}}" autofocus="" style="padding: 19px; border: solid 2px #000; resize: none; font-family: Roboto; font-weight: 400; font-size: 16px; vertical-align: top;"></p>
                <p><label for="bio"><b>About Me</b></label><br><textarea type="text" id="bio" name="bio" class="form-control" autofocus="" style="padding: 19px; border: solid 2px #000; resize: none; font-family: Roboto; font-weight: 400; font-size: 16px; height: 200px; vertical-align: top;" maxLength="288">{{bio}}</textarea></p>
                <p><button class="button" type="submit">Submit Changes</button></p>
            </form>
```

I know there is nothing wrong with the form or JQuery as I have used this before in similar situations.

So why can't I update the user data? Seems simple enough. I'm thinking it has to do with some kind of security feature that I'm not aware of. Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my updated "Edit Profile" view. I worked through this by trial and error, but I still don't know why it works now. I'm new to JavaScript, but it looks like it has to do with how Parse asynchronously updates the User object. I added a promise so that I could specify the submit function as the preferred callback:

```
EditMyProfileView = Parse.View.extend({
    template: Handlebars.compile($('#edit-my-profile-tpl').html()),
    events: {
        'submit .profile-details-edit': 'submit'
    },
    submit: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

    var form = document.getElementById("profile-details-edit");

    user = Parse.User.current();
    user.save().then(function() {
        var FullName = form.FullName.value;
        var bio = form.bio.value;
        user.set("FullName", FullName);
        user.set("bio", bio);
        form.submit();
        user.save();
    }, function(error) {

    });

},
```

If someone could specify exactly the difference between the two methods, and why the latter one works while the former doesn't, that would be greatly appreciated!